# what is the process when variable change to field,stack change to heap?

Tags: java, memory-management, jvm, heap-memory

i have a method

```
public static  RelationEntityWrapper findRelationByUserId(){
  //situation 1
   List<ObjectA> list = new ArrayList();
   ObjectA a1= new ObjectA();
   ObjectA a2= new ObjectA();
   list.add(a1);
   list.add(a2);
  //situation 2
   Relations.add(list);
}

public Relations(){
    public static LinkedBlockingQueue relationToDBQueue=new 
    LinkedBlockingQueue<ObjectA>(1024*1024);
    static{
       new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while (true) {              
                        try {
                            ObjectA info = relationToDBQueue.take();
                         }catch(Exception e){}
                }
     }}}
        public static void add(List<ObjectA> list) {
            try {
                for(ObjectA o :list)
                relationToDBQueue.add(o);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

**situation 1**

list,a1,a2 all are variable of method, so they're stored in stack

**situation 2**

the method variable will change to store in Relations's field relationToDBQueue,
list,a1,a2 variable will copy their stack memory to heap? what is the process at situation?

Thanks all your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java objects are never stored on the stack.  Always the heap.  But often, there are references to those objects on the stack.  In your example, those references are copied from the stack to the heap.

Comment: Offtopic: on your comment why that ArrayIndex... question has 116 upvotes. Simple: A) it is nicely written, pointing out the core problem B) it is out for long time, and when people do a good job, they DUP every new ArrayIndex thing to that one. So for sure, that question gets a lot of attention. I dont see anything wrong with that.